# Unable to build inline segments in RSiteCatalyst package in R

Tags: r, adobe-analytics, r-package

I am trying to build the inline segment to filter the pages (ex. to separate the  pages for blogs and games) using the function **BuildClassificationValueSegment()** to get the data from Adobe Analytics API,

I have tried some thing like

report.data.visits <- QueueTrended(reportsuite.id,date.from,date.to,metrics,elements,
segment.inline = BuildClassificationValueSegment("evar2","blog","OR")).

Got error like :

Error in ApiRequest(body = report.description, func.name = "Report.Validate") : 
  ERROR: segment_invalid  -  Segment "evar2" not valid for this company
In addition: Warning message:
In if (segment.inline != "") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Please help on the same.Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to declare the InlineSegment in advance and store it in a variable. Then pass it to the QueueTrended function.

I've been using the following syntax to generate an inline segment:

```
       InlineSegment <- list(container=list(type=unbox("hits"), 
                         rules=data.frame(
                            name=c("Page Name(eVar48)"),
                            element=c("evar48"), 
                            operator=c("equals"),
                            value=c(as.character("value1","value2"))
                         ))
```

You can change the *name* and *element* arguments in order to personalize the query.

The next step is to pass the InlineSegment to the QueueRanked function:

```
Report  <-  as.data.frame(QueueRanked("reportsuite",
                                       date.from = dateStart,
                                       date.to = dateEnd,
                                       metrics = c("pageviews"),
                                       elements = c("element"),
                                       segment.inline = InlineSegment,
                                       max.attempts=500))
```

I borrowed that syntax from this thread some time ago: https://github.com/randyzwitch/RSiteCatalyst/issues/129

**Please note** that there might be easier ways to obtain this kind of report without using InlineSegmentation. Maybe you can use the *selected* argument from the QueueRanked function in order to narrow down the scope of the report.

Also, I'm purposefully avoiding the *BuildClassificationValueSegment* function as I found it a bit difficult to understand.

Hope this workaround helps...