# Create multiple segment using API explorer in Adobe Anlaytics

Tags: adobe-analytics

I wanted to create multiple segment for multiple report suites using API explorer in Adobe Analytics. I am able to create a segment using the above described method but when i tried creating multiple segments at a time, i was facing some problem.

Below is the brief of what i did:
I selected 'Segments' as API and 'Save' as method in the developer connection.
Request API is REST 1.4 and Request is as below:

```
{
    "name":"Test1",
    "definition":{
        "container":{
            "type":"visits",
            "rules":[
                {
                    "element":"homePage",
                    "operator":"equals",
                    "value":"abc"
                 }
]
}
},

    "reportSuiteID":"rsidxxxx"
}
```

This is working fine, but when i request it for two segments at a time, only the second segment is getting created. Here is the example:

```
{

    "definition":{
        "container":{
            "type":"visits",
            "rules":[
                {
                    "element":"homePage",
                    "operator":"equals",
                    "value":"abc"
                         }
]
}
},
     "name":"Test1",
"reportSuiteID":"rsidxxxx",

"definition":{
        "container":{
            "type":"visits",
            "rules":[
                {
                    "element":"homePage",
                    "operator":"equals",
                    "value":"def"
                         }
]
}
},
            "name":"Test2",
    "reportSuiteID":"rsidxxxx"
}
```

Only Test2 segment is created from the above example.
Can you please suggest some other alternative so that both segments Test1 and Test2 could be created?

Answer (score 0):

[`Segments.Save`](https://marketing.adobe.com/developer/api-explorer#Segments.Save) does not currently allow for multiple segments to be created in one request. You must make a separate request for each segment.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same using RSiteCatalyst package in R? I tried using functions like 'segment.inline', 'BuildClassificationValueSegment' etc but getting errors. Link for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40211849/unable-to-build-inline-segments-in-rsitecatalyst-package-in-r .  Can you please help in this?

Comment: @SilkyJ I personally have not used RSiteCatalyst in R, but AFAIK there's only one Adobe API so RSiteCatalyst is almost certainly calling the same `Segments.Save` under the hood.

Comment: @SilkyJ sorry as mentioned, I do not have experience with RSiteCatalyst or R, so I'm afraid I will not be able to help with your linked question.